# 2008 Datacenter over Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing, datacenter

What are the advantages using windows 2008 Datacenter over Enterprise licensing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Datacenter allows more scalability and unlimited guests per CPU.  From a pure licensing perspective take a look at [this calculator page](http://www.microsoft.com/Windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-calculators.aspx) to see if datacenter is the correct fit for your environment

Answer (score 0):

well for virtualization DC gives you unlimited guests and EE give you 4 licenses.  Beyond that you'll need some real hardcore server apps to be able to utilize the the memory/cpu capacity difference between them!